# Get all text outside parenthesis while capturing word index

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How can I get all text that's *not* in parenthesis using `preg_match_all`? The reason I need to use `preg_match_all` is because I want to get the index of each word.

Given sentence:

> Hello how [t- are] you [t- today], Sir?

I can extract all the words *inside* the `( )`, which works. How can I also get all text outside the `( )` separately?

```
preg_match_all('/\[t-(.*?)\]/', $this->target, $targetWords, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  are
            [1] => 47
        ),
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  today
            [1] => some number
        )

)
```

---

**Note**: I already know about `preg_split`:

```
$outsideParenthesis = preg_split('/\[.*?\]/', $this->target);
```

But this doesn't allow me to maintain the index.

---

**Note 2:**  It may help to provide my end goal:

I want to take a string of custom markdown. For each word, I want to generate word objects that specify their type and content.

The reason is, I'd like to send an array of word objects in order to the frontend so I can loop through the array and generate HTML elements with classes, so I can apply styling as needed.

And I want to be able to specify any markdown within, e.g.,

> Hello how [t- are] you [k- today], Sir?

Where t- is target, k- is key.

So the final array I'd like would look like:

```
[
   [
      type => 'normal'
      content => 'Hello how '
   ],
   [
      type => 'target'
      content => 'are'
   ],
   [
      type => 'normal'
      content => ' you'
   ]
   [
      type => 'key'
      content => 'today'
   ]
   [
      type => 'normal'
      content => ', Sir?'
   ]
]
```

Here's my wordObjects function as of now:

```
private function setWordObjects($array, $type)
{
    return array_map(function ($n) use ($type) {
        return [
            'type' => $type,
            'content' => $n[0],
            'index' => $n[1]
        ];
    }, $array[1]);
}
```

Comment: A splitting approach suggested by Roman below is much more natural than trying [to match the parts other than your pattern](https://ideone.com/5vcIuA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended solution:

```
$s = 'Hello how [t- are] you [k- today], Sir?';
$types = ['t-' => 'target', 'k-' => 'key'];
$splitted = preg_split('/\[([tk]- [^]]+)\]/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$result = [];
foreach ($splitted as $v) {
    [$content, $pos] = $v;
    $k = substr($content, 0, 2);
    $is_delim = isset($types[$k]);
    $result[] = array_combine(['type', 'content', 'index'],
                              [$is_delim? $types[$k] : 'normal',
                              $is_delim? substr($content, 3) : $content,
                              $is_delim? $pos + 3 : $pos]);
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => normal
            [content] => Hello how 
            [index] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => target
            [content] => are
            [index] => 14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => normal
            [content] =>  you 
            [index] => 18
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => key
            [content] => today
            [index] => 27
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => normal
            [content] => , Sir?
            [index] => 33
        )
)
```

Comment: Does this also give me the index of the substring?

Comment: @Growler, see the output

Comment: @Growler I do not quite get what the expected output should be, probably, you do not need `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` that returns the captured part.

Comment: @Growler, according to Note2 you don't need the offsets, but some keywords. That's different. Do you still need to capture offsets?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest okay— I don't know PHP well enough. How can I accomplish Note 2 in the best way?

Comment: @Growler, you have my completed solution

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest wonderful! Thanks so much. Btw this syntax `[$content, $pos] = $v;` is array destructuring you get in something like JavaScript ES6, but gave me a parse error in PHP. Do I need something to parse this?

Comment: @Growler, welcome. This `[$content, $pos] = $v;` is PHP 7 flavour (array unpacking). Use `list($content, $pos) = $v;` for older versions

Answer (score 2):

With `preg_match_all`

```
$str = 'Hello how [t- are] you [k- today], Sir?';

$types = ['' => 'normal', 't' => 'target', 'k' => 'key'];

if ( preg_match_all('~ (?| \[ (?<type>[^]-]+) - \h (?<content>[^]]+) ]
                         | () ([^[]+) ) ~x', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
    foreach ($matches as &$m) {
        unset($m[0], $m[1], $m[2]);
        $m['type'] = $types[$m['type']];
    }
    print_r($matches);
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/A1orX)

Comment: This is better than the other answer but you forgot to include *PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE*. As per requirements.

Comment: @revo: Thanks, about the offset part, It's unclear if he want it or not (see the note 2 in the question) and it's also unclear which offset he wants (the position of the bracket, the one of the string, should I subtract the length of the brackets or not ...). But it's indeed possible to use PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE. [example with the "string" position without corrections](https://3v4l.org/GgTkT)

Comment: @revo I only cared about the index in the context of splicing key words in later into the full sentence by index. This solution removes that need as it breaks the words into objects in order.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte would you be able to explain that complicated regex? `~ (?| \[ (?<type>[^]-]+) - \h (?<content>[^]]+) ]| () ([^[]+) ) ~x` is very confusing to me

Comment: @Growler: (?| ... | ... | ... ) is a branch reset group. A branch reset group has the same capture groups in each of these alternatives. That means that () is also the named capture group 'type' and ([^[]+) is also the named capture group 'content'. With the branch reset you only have to deal with two capture groups with the correct name instead of four. The x modifier switches on the free-spacing mode in the pattern (white spaces aren't taken in account).

Comment: @Growler: note that it's also possible to use the J modifier that allows duplicate named captures in the same pattern (but in this case when the second branch succeeds, four groups are created): [example](https://3v4l.org/BthQE)

Comment: Why would I need duplicate named captures?

Comment: @Growler: The goal of these patterns is to return capture groups in an associative array ( the one you are looking for ). That's why I use named captures. I speak about duplicated named captures and branch reset because by default you don't have the right to use two times the same name for capture groups in the same pattern. Make a `print_r($matches);` just after the `preg_match_all` to see the returned structure.